# Get the existing margin on a pdf page

Tags: python, c, perl, unix, pdf

I need to get the existing margins(left, right, top, bottom) on a page of pdf file in perl, here is the code to get the dimension of padf page.

## !/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CAM::PDF;
    
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('test2.pdf');

my $num_page=$pdf->numPages();
print "Total Pages : $num_page\n";

my ($x,$y,$width,$height)=$pdf->getPageDimensions(2);
print "Dimension of PDF File : $width x $height  px \n";

$width=sprintf("%.2f",$width/72);   # PPI/DPI Conversion (72 px = 1 inch)
$height=sprintf("%.2f",$height/72);

print "Dimension of PDF File is : $width x $height inch \n"
```

Comment: Please make your question title a **short** description of the issue (4-5 words), and explain your problem **in detail** in the body (use the [edit] link for that please).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PDF file is not like a Word document, you cannot change "margins" and have the text reflow itself to the new size.  It is more like an image snapshot (i.e. a TIFF file) of a *rendered* document that has been formatted and laid out on the page.  Thus there is no concept of a "margin" setting in a PDF.  At that point it's a blank page with a bunch of objects placed on it.  It just happens that *most* of the objects are contained within a large box that was defined by the margins when the page was laid out.

You could approximate the margins by looking at the bounding box of every object on the page, but you'd have to ignore stuff that is normally outside the "margins", such as page headers/footers and page number, margin notes, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jim, But all what i need is the size of white spaces before text starts form left, right, top & bottom.